# Eclipse (No JVM was found)

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse gave me an error specifying that no JRE is installed while I was trying to configure Erlide in eclipse.

I added path to erlang directory in 'System Variables'. Then I installed erlang plugin for eclipse, added erlang installation directory path in Eclipse preferences and restarted Eclipse.

After restarting eclipse started giving me error about JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below steps might help you to solve your problem.

1. Install JDK and JRE - Here are step by step [Instructions](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html) OR [ANOTHER](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/rel/3.3/win/gs/html/getstart_win32/before_starting.htm)
2. Verify you setup JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME and PATH into environment variable.

   You can also investigate your Java version via Command Prompt:

   Open a Command Prompt (Navigate to “Start” => “Run” and type “cmd”)

   Then enter the following command:

   java –version

   If you don't see your java version you have to follow step 1 carefully again
3. Installed eclipse/ if already installed open the same. Here are step by step [Instructions](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/javaeclipseinstallation.html)

NOTE: Make sure that you have same bits for both JDK and EClipse (32 or 64). One way is to verify in your ini file.

Answer (score 0):

To develop a Java program, you need a JDK not only a JRE.

Comment: Before installing Erlang plugin, Eclipse was running fine. I also have Java JDK with NetBeans installed and it is working

Comment: What is your Eclipse, Java and Erlide version?

Comment: Eclipse Version is 4.4. JDK version is 8+.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a JDK installed? Have you tried to run `jar`, `$ set | grep "JAVA_HOME"` (Linux) or `C:\> set | find "JAVA_HOME"` (Windows) in your command prompt to see if you have Java configured in your machine?

Once you install your JDK you need to set this environment variable.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set environment variables?

Comment: Windows: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

Comment: Command which you asked to run returned "JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jre8"

Comment: JRE = Java Runtime Environment, i.e., Client JVM to run Java apps, that does not allow you to build Java applications, you need to install a Java Development Kit (JDK).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Earlide is not compatible with your JDK 1.8, can you try with jdk 1.6